# Sum of cells containing a percentage % character

Tags: excel-formula, office365

I have a column (in Excel) which contains either text or a percentage figure. For example:

> yes
>   no
>   yes
>   50%
>   75%
>   no

I want to sum all of the percentages together.

I have tried:

```
sumif(C4:C15,"?%?",C4:C15)
```

But I got 0.0.

Why I cant use '%', and how can I fix it?

Comment: I have applied some formatting to your question to make it more readable. It could be improved further I think, but that will need some input from you. Could you [edit] the question to give some more detail - particularly this point: where a cell has a percentage character, is that a number with percentage formatting, or a string with the percentage character really in the cell value?

Comment: If A4 is your cell with a percentage character, in an empty cell use this formula and tell us the results:  `=istext(A4)`.  Also are there any other number that may be in the list or just percentage?  it may be easier just to sum the numbers if all numbers are percentages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use regular `=SUM(C4:C15)`. It will ignore the text cells.